# Cannot predict input from ImageNet classes [Keras + Tensorflow]

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, imagenet

I followed this repo (https://github.com/iamgroot42/keras-finetuning), I've done with the training.

Now, I want to predict my input image both of my own dataset (containing 2 classes, Avocado & Mango) and ImageNet set. But the prediction result always returning both of index 0 or 1 (I guess it was avocado or mango), never returning a class from ImageNet. E.g. I want to predict an iPod image that came from ImageNet original class, but the model.predict(...) always returning 0 and 1.

My model-labels.json:

```
["avocados", "mangos"]
```

My code for prediction:

```
img = imresize(imread('ipod.png', mode='RGB'), (224, 224)).astype(np.float32)
img[:, :, 0] -= 123.68
img[:, :, 1] -= 116.779
img[:, :, 2] -= 103.939
img[:,:,[0,1,2]] = img[:,:,[2,1,0]]
img = img.transpose((2, 0, 1))
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
img = img.reshape(img.shape[0], n, n, n_chan)

out = model.predict(img, batch_size=batch_size)
pred = np.argmax(out, axis=1)

print(pred)
```

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: Can you post your model definition?

Comment: @avijit-dasgupta Here is the full script: github.com/iamgroot42/keras-finetuning/blob/master/net.py

Answer (score 1):

maybe you just need to translate between `class index` to `imagenet labels`?

try to:

```
from imagenet_utils import decode_predictions

[...]

img = imresize(imread('ipod.png', mode='RGB'), (224, 224)).astype(np.float32)
img[:, :, 0] -= 123.68
img[:, :, 1] -= 116.779
img[:, :, 2] -= 103.939
img[:,:,[0,1,2]] = img[:,:,[2,1,0]]
img = img.transpose((2, 0, 1))
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
img = img.reshape(img.shape[0], n, n, n_chan)

out = model.predict(img, batch_size=batch_size)
#add decoding line here to get the top 3
print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(out, top=3)[0])
```

size)